# SQL Server 2005 script with join across Database Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join

I have the following script which I use to give me a simple "diff" between tables on two different databases. (Note: In reality my comparison is on a lot more than just an ID)

```
SELECT
    MyTableA.MyId,
    MyTableB.MyId
FROM
    MyDataBaseA..MyTable MyTableA
FULL OUTER JOIN
    MyDataBaseB..MyTable MyTableB
ON
    MyTableA.MyId = MyTableB.MyId
WHERE
    MyTableA.MyId IS NULL
OR
    MyTableB.MyId IS NULL
```

I now need to run this script on two databases that exist on different servers. At the moment my solution is to backup the database from one server, restore it to the other and then run the script.

I'm pretty sure this is possible, however, is this likely to be a can of worms? This is a very rare task I need to perform and if it involves a large number of DB setting changes then I will probably stick to my backup method.

Comment: Why not consider putting place SSIS package to pump data from one server to another. This eliminates a need to mess with linked servers and performance will not be very different

Comment: This is a one off check of a few tables over two databases. There is no requirement at all to maintain the data. The databases are different and should be different. This is just a way to sanity check that only the things that should be different are.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a Linked Server in SQL you can just run a regular query like so.
This is assuming that MyDatabaseB is on the remote server that you set up the linked server to and the query is being run on the server that has MyDatabaseA.

```
SELECT
MyTableA.MyId,
MyTableB.MyId
FROM
MyDataBaseA..MyTable MyTableA
FULL OUTER JOIN
LinkedServerName.MyDataBaseB.dbo.MyTable MyTableB
ON
MyTableA.MyId = MyTableB.MyId
WHERE
MyTableA.MyId IS NULL
OR
MyTableB.MyId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I too would recommend SSIS instead. Have two data sources one that `select ID from MyTableA order by ID` and one that `select ID from MyTableB order by ID`. The ORDER BY is important, and you'll need to go into the advanced editor and mark the output as sorted by ID in both sources. Then plug these two sources into a Merge Join transformation and specify that is a Full join type. Then you plug the output of the join into a Conditional Split Transformation and separate the rows with non-NULL A and B IDs from the ones that have NULL on either A's ID or B's ID. These last ones will be your 'diff'.

In my experience, as the table size will grow larger, the SSIS solution will become more and more appealing as the plan generated for the distributed query will become unmanageably inefficient.